# Rails 4 user model will not save with hash data from oauth

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, oauth

I am trying to add oauth to an existing login for my project, but when I retrieve the hash data and try to save the user params with `user.save!`, the validation rules fail.

**user.rb**

```
has_secure_password

validates :email, :format => { :with => /\A[^@ ]+@[^@ ]+\.[^@ ]+\Z/ },
:uniqueness => { :case_sensitive => false }

validates :password, :presence => true, :on => :create

validates :username,
  :format => { :with => /\A[A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9_-]{0,24}\Z/ },
  :uniqueness => { :case_sensitive => false }
```

...

```
class << self
  def from_omniauth(auth_hash)
    user = find_or_create_by(uid: auth_hash['uid'], provider: auth_hash['provider'])
    user.name = auth_hash['info']['name']
    user.email = auth_hash['info']['email']
    user.username = auth_hash['info']['email']
    user.save!
    user
  end
end
```

The output of `user.errors.full_messages` gives me `["Password can't be blank", "Password can't be blank", "Email is invalid", "Username is invalid"]`.

What I don't understand is why the validations are failing if the data parameters have been defined (i.e. `user.email`) and hold the correct values.

What am I missing?

Comment: Password is blank.. I am guessing ur username regex doesnt allow @.. I dunno about why email is invalid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your problem is the `find_or_create_by` method.

this will looking for the user with `uid` and `provider` otherwise try to create it.

but without vaild username, and so on, it will always fail if there is no user with `uid` and `provider`

**update:**

> you try to find a user with an `uid` and a `provider`. if
>   `find_or_create_by` find a valid user, it will return it. with this
>   you can update the data.
>
> **BUT** if `find_or_create_by` did not find a valid user, it will create a user with the given parameter `uid` and `provider`. but to
>   create a valid user, your model needs a valid username, a valid
>   `password`, and a valid `email`

you could do something like this

```
def from_omniauth(auth_hash)
  user = User.find_by(uid: auth_hash['uid'], provider:auth_hash['provider']) || User.new(uid: auth_hash['uid'], provider:auth_hash['provider'], password: 'your password methods')

  user.name = auth_hash['info']['name']
  user.email = auth_hash['info']['email']
  user.username = auth_hash['info']['email']
  user.save!
  user
end
```

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. As you said, if it doesn't find an user with `uid` and `provider`, it tries to create it, which is what I want to happen. As I understand it, if an user doesn't exist, it should create a new record using the hash info. If the user does exist, it should just update the record and return the data.

Comment: @alphaleonis yes. thats right. but your user is invalid. it just has an `uid` and a `provider` but it also needs a valid username, a valid emailaddress and a password. you could check if user exists, and update them or create a new once, in 2 steps

Comment: Isn't that what `save!` does? If `user.email` and `user.username` hold values, shouldn't they save as the `user_params`?

Comment: @alphaleonis sure thats right. i updated my answer with more information, to show why your code failed

Comment: I see what you did there. That gets rid of all the errors, but it still won't save for some reason.

Comment: @alphaleonis ah i see. i forget to add the password. i updated the answer. the password is needed if its a new user